# update a sales object witin a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an issue, is it possible to update the sales Object "Individual" in a journey with a object activity because i don't have access to this object in the list of available objects proposed by the object activity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the issue. Do you have access to that object in Contact Builder? The permissions of the object are configured at a global level (marketing cloud connector) not at a marketing cloud user level.